# Browser automation in html/ web application

Tags: javascript, php, html, selenium

I have been doing alot of research into seeing if it is possible to perform browser automation from within the web browser using html/javascript etc.

Now i have heard of Selenium but this does not work from with in the browser.

My plan is to simply have the user have open my website and then my website automatically "googles" a set search term and then clicks on the top result for them.

It has to happen from a UI perspective thats why browser automation is key. Is there anything anyone can recommend to put me on the right tracks of doing this from within the browser.

Comment: No, your code cannot take control of the browser in which it is running. That would be a security nightmare.

Comment: Then Selenium isn't what you need thus it works with Browsers. If this works in your case I would use an iframe with the search result for the set search term. If you want to modify the UI of the result I would check whether Google provides a respective API or you can write a crawler that crawls the google result list and then you process it by your needs. After a quick search I have found this: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: this does not sound fraudulent at all ;)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

First, I would start with understanding how Google's search engine interprets and handles search strings. For example, the following text typed into the search bar "conduct a search" results in the following URL: https://www.google.com/#q=conduct+a+search&* . There are of course many different search criteria and filters possible so you will want to explore these, but most basic text searches can likely just be URL encoded.

Second, I would look into iframes. From [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp): `<iframe src="URL"></iframe>`. Using jQuery you could fire an event once the iframe is loaded (`$(document).load()` or `$(document).ready()` should suffice) that fires the `onclick()` of the first `<a>` found within the search results.

Finally, I would be aware of Google's [policies](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66357?hl=en) on such matters. Because the system you are recommending is not *completely* automated but rather driven by user-input you may get Google to give you permission.

Comment: When a downvote of the question results in the downvote of an answer...